# Contingency table and pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart, contingency

I have created a vector with a series of values, like this

```
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[48] 2 2 2 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 4 4 5 4 5 4 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 6 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 4 4
[95] 5 5 5 5 3 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 5 7 6 7 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 7 7 5 6 5 7 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 7 7 6 6 6 7 6 6 5 6 6
[142] 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 6
```

If I summarize the vector with

```
table(myVector)
```

I get this:

```
 myVector
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 1 49  1 15 42 33  9
```

Now, I create a pie chart from that vector. Easy enough, I just do this:

```
count=table(myVector)
pie(count)
```

And it works.

But the instructions in my textbook of reference says:
"Plot the new vector using a Pie chart. Remember that you must create a contingency table to that end."

I don't get that part. How can I create a contingency table from a single vector and why is it any relavant to create a Pie chart ?

Is the "table(myVector)" I did earlier a contingency table or am I asked to do something else ?

I read several web pages about contingency tables but it is abstract and I never crossed any example with a single vector.

So I'm quite confused about what it is and why it is necessary. All I seem to get is that it allows to put variables in relation but with a single vector, I fail to understand how I can do that and what it is necessary for.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're right, the authors are wrong :)

Comment: I disagree with with @ktiu, the author is entirely right. But so are you: you *are* using a contingency table. It’s the result of `table(myVector)`.

Comment: Ok, it's reassuring, thanks. I wasn't familiar with the fact that table(), in that case, was a contingency one per se.

Comment: It's an interesting semantic question whether contingency tables can be univariate. (I tend to go with [this definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContingencyTable.html).) But I guess that's a question for CrossValidated. As far as R documentation is concerned, you are correct that `table()` is described as outputting a contingency table.